# Convert a D3 v3 Grouped bar chart to v4 Y Axis labels

Tags: d3.js, jsfiddle

I'm trying convert https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051 which is v3 to v4

I have it working apart from the y axis

https://jsfiddle.net/andytela/xqkrdzq4/1/

The ticks aren't appearing.
The values appear to be coming back from the `y.domain` but are not appearing

Can any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were scaling the y-axis using the wrong equation, also you're missing the styling for the text to show up.

```
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
   .ticks(10)


text {
  fill: black;
}
```

I've corrected the jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xqkrdzq4/3/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. That helps massively I have a few different graphs running and this final hurdle just stumped me